# String to JSONArray reverses order

Tags: java, arrays, json, collections

I have a String named 'cachedResult' that I need to convert into JSONArray.
The String 'cachedResult' is:

```
[{"lastname":"Cashier 100","count":3},{"lastname":"Cashier 227","count":21},{"lastname":"Cashier 301","count":24},{"lastname":"Cashier 231","count":51}]
```

When I convert it into JSONArray by:

```
def resultJsonArray=new JSONArray(cachedResult)
```

It gives back the output of toString() as:

```
[{"count":3,"lastname":"Cashier 100"},{"count":21,"lastname":"Cashier 227"},{"count":24,"lastname":"Cashier 301"},{"count":51,"lastname":"Cashier 231"}]
```

The order of string was lastnames and then count . But the JSONArray formed out of that String gives a reverse order(sorted order i guess) count and then lastname.

I want output be same as the input(same order).
Please Help,Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the ordering of JSON matter to you? Because how ever the internal order me, the Parsing technique won't change and would yield you the correct/desired result.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not a real answer to your question but you should not rely on the order of a JSON object:

> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs. An object
>   begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

(see: [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/))

So you should make sure your code does not depend on a certain order of keys/value pairs inside JSON objects.